# Changes not applying into php.ini

Tags: php, centos, phar

Im using centos os and I have to make some changes in `php.ini` and set

```
 phar.readonly  = 0
```

in order to use phar. 
I got a php.ini which is in `/etc` . By changes I restart web server but when I look into `phpinfo()` , nothing has changed.

when use phar in Terminal :

```
  Fatal error : Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'creating archive "./build/myapp.phar" disabled by the php.ini setting phar.readonly'
```

Give some tips hints or something please, thanks

**EDIT :**

**`Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini`**

Comment: If I remember right `phpinfo()` under loaded configuration file or something, will show you the location of the loaded php.ini file.  If I recall correctly

Comment: my php.ini file location is `/etc/php.ini` !!!!!!

Comment: why minus point my question???!!

Comment: what about "Additional .ini files parsed"?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple php.ini files.
Find out which one is being used by running `php -i` or calling `phpinfo()`

Comment: I have one php.ini file  `/etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

IF php.ini file is corrupted it will load defaults.

If you want to know where is php loading php.ini from OR you want to check for php.ini validity, run:

```
php -i
```

Run that command and if there is something wrong with the file it will tell you (check image). As well as file location

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure you edit the correct file. you can see the path of php.ini from phpinfo();

then, you need to restart you php

```
 systemctl restart php-fpm
```